# What does $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt2}\right)$ equal exactly?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt2}\right)$$

I can't work out how to answer this in **exact form**?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})=\pi/3$

Answer (score 4):

$$\tan x = \sqrt3\\
x = 60^\circ, \space\pi/3$$

Always remember the $1, \sqrt3, 2$ triangle

Comment: Put a vertical line of length 2 above that triangle and you get $\tan 75^{\circ}=2+\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan^{-1}\left({\sqrt\frac6 2}\right)$$
$$=\tan^{-1}\left({\sqrt3}\right)$$
$$=60^\circ or \space\pi/3$$

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle\tan \frac\pi3=\sqrt3,$ the general value of $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3)$ is $\displaystyle n\pi+\frac\pi3$ where $n$ is any integer

As the [principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) value of $\displaystyle\tan^{-1}x$ lies in $\displaystyle\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right],$ the principal  value of $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3)$ will be $\displaystyle\frac\pi3$